# How to theme all pages after a certain url

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 8.7.8

I would like to create a new twig theme file for all pages that are after a certain URL. 
For example: example.com/example/this-page

"This-page" is what I want to create my twig file for. But there doesn't seem to be an option in the theme debugging for anything after example.com/example.

Another example...The twig file would be named page--example.html.twig ... Is there no way to say page--example/*.html.twig ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter to create your own template suggestions!

In your theme:

File: `my_theme/my_theme.theme`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter.
 */
function my_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);

  if (strpos($current_path, 'this-page') !== false) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__this_page';
  }
}
```

File: `my_theme/templates/page--this-page.html.twig`

```
// Output html and stuff
```

Obviously replace "my_theme" with the name of your custom theme.

Here is a [nice tutorial](https://befused.com/drupal/page-template-content-type) that expands more on it.